# How to correct data validation issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel column formatted as Percentage. I have a Custom data validation formula:

```
=OR(AND(E3>0,E3<=1),(E3="N/A"))
```

I.e., I'm trying to ensure values from 0 to 100 or N/A as text.
The rule works. I can enter (say) 45, and it shows up as 45% in the cell, or "N/A".

However, if (say) I enter 101, I get the expected error popup. But if I select RETRY, and enter (say) 45, I get the same error. If instead I enter 0.45, this is accepted and displayed as 45% in the cell.

How can I get the validation to accept 45 instead of 0.45 if the RETRY path is taken?
Thanks.

Comment: May be this `=OR(AND(E3/100>0,E3/100<=1),(E3="N/A"))`

Comment: Thanks, but that now permits values such as 101... to be considered valid.

Comment: No, it doesn't it will give you an error pop up. asking you to enter values between 0 to 100. That is because -->`101/100` is `1.01` which is greater than `1`. Note that my cells are pre formatted as percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to explicitly add the "%", i.e., "45%" vs. "45".

Unfortunately, this differs from standard input, where I can just type "45" into the cell and it appears as 45%.

Oh well.